# android : post data to webview

Tags: android, post, encoding, webview

I am using Webview to send data to exchange mail server . ( http post did not work for mails with large attachments and hence hence trying this method ).

Please see my code below.

If I send data with no encoding at all, sending fails.
If I do as per my code below where I do encoding for the whole data , it still fails.

If i try the commented code , where I store the data as name valuepairs and encode that , mail is received but there is no attachment. So what is the right way to do encoding here? The type of attachment is ContentBody . All other parameters are string.

```
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,);
            entity.addPart("hidid", new StringBody(hidid));
            entity.addPart("hidchk", new StringBody(hidchk));
            entity.addPart("hidcanary", new StringBody(canary));
           entity.addPart("attach", attachment);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            entity.writeTo(bytes);
            String fullUrl = baseUrl + "?ae=Dialog&t=Attach&a=Add";
        webView.postUrl(fullUrl, EncodingUtils.getBytes(bytes.toString(),"BASE64"));


          /*  List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hidid", hidid)); 
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hidchk", hidchk)); 
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hidcanary", canary)); 
            parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attach", attachment.toString()));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity1 = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters); 
String fullUrl = baseUrl + "?ae=Dialog&t=Attach&a=Add";
   webView.postUrl(fullUrl, EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity1)); */
```

i see that he Android WebView::postUrl method is harder coded for "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" .

Comment: Do you get any failure message in logcat?

Comment: Yes i get error response which is : outlook web access not able to process request

Comment: try converting your attachment into base64 in the commented code

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your attachment as

```
 public static String encodeToBase64(String string)
    {
        String encodedString = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] byteData = null;
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) // Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO --> 8
            {
                byteData = android.util.Base64.encode(string.getBytes(),android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
            }
            else
            {
                byteData = Base64Utility.encode(string.getBytes(),Base64Utility.DEFAULT);
            }
            encodedString = new String(byteData);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return encodedString;
    }
```

to base64

Comment: i edited my code to do that . But again mail is received with no attachment .

Comment: parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hidcanary", canary)); 
           // parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attach", attachment.toString()));
             parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attach", encodeToBase64(attachment.toString())));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity1 = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);  
            String fullUrl = baseUrl + "?ae=Dialog&t=Attach&a=Add";
   webView.postUrl(fullUrl,EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity1));

Comment: UrlEncodedFormEntity already does the encoding i guess, so doeas again encoding the attachment make any differences ?

Comment: @preetha from where do you add your attachment to webview and from where do you send mail?

Comment: this code is for uploading attachment . After this post i check the response and then send mail

Comment: @preetha After converting your attachment to base64, add it like new StringBody(base64attachment) and not as byte array

Comment: where exactly ? namevalue pair expects string and post url expect bytesarray as second parameter

Comment: MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                       entity.addPart("hidchk", new StringBody(encodeToBase64(hidchk)));
            entity.addPart("hidcanary", new StringBody(encodeToBase64(canary)));
           entity.addPart("attach", new StringBody(encodeToBase64(attachment.toString())));
                     ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            entity.writeTo(bytes);
                        String fullUrl = baseUrl + "?ae=Dialog&t=Attach&a=Add";
   webView.postUrl(fullUrl,EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity));

Comment: i tried like above and it again didnt work , mail goes but no attachmnet coming (; . Thanks for youyr replies

Answer (score 0):

```
bytes.toString()
```

creates a String from your bytes. Use `toBytesArray()` instead, to obtain a byte[]

Then, EncodingUtils encodes using a Charset. BASE64 is not a Charset. UTF-8 is. If you want to Base64-encode your bytes, use `android.util.Base64.encode(byte[]);`

In your example :

```
webView.postUrl(fullUrl, Base64.encode(bytes.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: this may not be the way your server expects data.

Answer (score 0):

Per a [blog post about using MultipartEntity to post data to a url](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/), you may need to include some additional jar files in your project.  They include the following apache open-source projects:  apache-mime4j, httpclient, httpcore and httpmime.

Once you do that, you should be able to use the following code as an example to post both string & files to a url:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.tumblr.com/api/write");

try {
  MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

  entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo"));
  entity.addPart("data", new FileBody(image));
  httppost.setEntity(entity);
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: i have all these , but server has a size restriction when i send like this . it responds with error

Comment: If the server has a size restriction, you trying it through a webView isn't going to make any difference!  Do you have access to the server?